# .join() function returns int instead of str. What went wrong?

Tags: python, join, typeerror

```
index = 0
manage = {}
filedata = open(custom_path,'r')
for status in filedata:
    manage[index] = status
    print manage[index]
    index += 1
```

The output from the above print manage[index] is correct, showing:

```
yes

yes

yes

yes

yes
```

Then, i added a new line:
    manage = str(u'\n,'.join(manage))

and got the following error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

Changed my code to:

```
values = ','.join(str(status) for status in manage)

print values
```

And got the following output (which is wrong):

```
0,1,2,3,4
```

I was expecting: yes,yes,yes,yes,yes

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`manage` is a dictionary that has integer keys. The for-loop iterates over dictionary keys. Change it to: `','.join(line.strip() for line in manage.values())`.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the keys in your dictionary rather than the values.

Try changing this line:

```
values = ','.join(str(status) for status in manage)
```

To This:

```
values = ','.join(val.rstrip("\n") for val in manage.values())
```

This is also why you get that error, because you tried using your keys.

Comment: you might mean `manage.items()` in the second loop. Though keys are not used so you could use `manage.values()` to get only dictionary values.

Comment: manage = ','.join(str(val) for status, val in manage.values()) returns the following error: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @TingPing You got this when error when you changed your code? Take a look at the other answers too.

Answer (score 1):

This is because manage is a dict not a list, as defined in

```
manage = {}
```